# Why can a non-const reference parameter be bound to a temporary object?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, object-lifetime, temporary-objects

```
char f1();
void f2(char&);

struct A {};

A    f3();
void f4(A&);

int main()
{
    f2(f1()); // error C2664. This is as expected.
    f4(f3()); // OK! Why???
}
```

> error C2664: 'void f4(char &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char'
>   to 'char &'

I have been taught that in C++ a non-const reference parameter cannot be bound to a temporary object; and in the code above, `f2(f1());` triggers an error as expected.

However, why does the same rule not apply to the code line `f4(f3());`?

PS: My compiler is VC++ 2013. Even if I comment the line `f2(f1());`, then the code containing `f4(f3());` will be compiled without any errors or warnings.

**Update:**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfbk5ddc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says:

> In previous releases of Visual C++, non-const references could be
>   bound to temporary objects. Now, temporary objects can only be bound
>   to const references.

So I think it is a bug of VC++. I have submitted a bug report to [VC++ team](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807118/temporary-objects-can-be-bound-to-non-const-references)

Comment: Did you try building without f2(f1()) in the code?  It may be stopping at the first error.

Comment: If I comment the line `f2(f1());`, then the code will be OK.

Comment: MSVC is known for supporting this as compiler extension. Not sure about 2013.

Comment: f1() should return a reference.

Comment: @yngum, compiler extension? Could you refer me to the MSDN page?

Comment: @xmllmx just google `msvc const reference temporary`.

Comment: @yngum, MSDN says: In previous releases of Visual C++, non-const references could be bound to temporary objects. Now, temporary objects can only be bound to const references. So I think this is a bug.

Comment: MS used to warn you about this and allow it anyway since their implementation did not efficiently unbind the reference  as most compilers do. If they now flag it as an outright error, that's a *good* thing, because thats what it is by the standard. Their non-standard extension work on this regard was anything-but helpful, as it promoted non-portable code.

Comment: @James, Could you move your comment to an answer? I think it is the correct answer. If you leave it a comment, then I cannot select it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @xmllmx: It is not a bug, but a compiler extension that can be disabled in compiler settings. By default extensions are enabled, meaning that be defualt the code will compile even in VS2012. You have to disable them explicitly. In all versions of MS compiler it is done by `/Za` switch

Comment: @AndreyT, According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfbk5ddc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx, it should be treated as a bug.

Comment: @xmllmx: I don't see what on that page made you think it should be treated as a bug. It was definitely a poorly implemented extension (a bug) in VC6, where it interfered with overload resolution, thus breaking conformant code. But by VS2005 it was reworked into a genuine extension. That's what it seems to remain to this day. What made you perceive it as a bug (as opposed to an extension)?

Comment: @AndreyT, If my compiler is pre-VC++ 2008, then this is not a bug. However, MSDN explicitly says: "Now, temporary objects can only be bound to const references.", and my compiler is VC++ 2013, so it is sure to be a bug.

Comment: @xmllmx: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The article you linked is written specifically for VS2003 (or VS2005, it is not really clear). However, in VS2003, VS2005, VS2010 and VS2012 the behavior remained unchanged: it is controlled by `/Za` flag. So, the MSDN article is either plainly wrong by making such "unconditional" assertion or we are simply missing the context for that article (presented elsewhere). I don't know how it works in VS2013, but I expect it to be the same. In any case, VS2013 is a completely different story, not related to that article.

Comment: In other words, if there's a "bug" here, it is a bug in the article you linked, not a bug in the compiler. The compiler works as intended. And the behavior is the modern versions of the compiler satisfies the requirements of a "language extension", meaning that it is not a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile with [the /Za option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) to disable language extensions, the compiler rejects both calls:

```
> cl /Za test.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(11): error C2664: 'void f2(char &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'char &'
test.cpp(12): error C2664: 'void f4(A &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'A' to 'A &'
        A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
```

There are several (very constrained) circumstances in which the compiler, with language extensions enabled, will still allow a non-const lvalue reference to bind to an rvalue expression.  My understanding is that this is largely to avoid breaking several enormous legacy codebases that rely on this "extension."

(In general, use of /Za is not recommended for many reasons, but mostly because the Windows SDK headers cannot be #included with the /Za option.)

Answer (score 2):

You compiler is not standard-compliant (maybe this is documented compiler extension?). GCC gives the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:11:11: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char&' from an rvalue of type 'char'
    f2(f1()); // error C2664. This is as expected.
        ^
main.cpp:2:6: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void f2(char&)'
void f2(char&);
    ^
main.cpp:12:12: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A'
    f4(f3()); // OK! Why???
            ^
main.cpp:7:6: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void f4(A&)'
void f4(A&);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the compiler option /permissive- (Configuration Properties > C/C++ > All Options > Conformance Mode) also disables Microsoft language extensions (per James McNellis' answer) and will break non-conforming code.

> This option disables permissive behaviors, and sets the /Zc compiler options for strict conformance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160

For reference I was using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9.4 and compiling for the v142 platform toolset.