# Taking reference of rvalue

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue, rvalue

according to the open standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html)

This code should give an error:

```
A&  a_ref3 = A();  // Error!
A&& a_ref4 = A();  // Ok
```

However, I am able to do the first line just fine. And the second line actually errors for me. I am compiling with Visual C++14 in Visual Studio.

```
class foo {

};

int main()
{

    foo x;
    foo() = x; // Valid

    foo& fr = foo(); // Valid

    string&& foo = "hey"; // Valid r reference

    foo&& frr = foo(); // Error!

    return 0;
}
```

So I guess my question is that is foo() an lvalue? And if so, why does Stroustrup say that you cannot assign a reference type to it?

Comment: The first line should be an error if you disable language extensions. I'm not sure what's up with the second one not working.

Comment: `foo&& frr = foo();` fails because you've redeclared `foo` as a `std::string&&`, change the name of the variable in the line above.

Comment: Can you fine gents please copy your message to the answer section so I can accept it? It looks like language extensions are not complying to ISO C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo& fr = foo();` works in VC++ because the compiler [allows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697616/why-can-a-non-const-reference-parameter-be-bound-to-a-temporary-object) it, clang and gcc both reject this syntax.

`foo&& frr = foo();` on the other hand is an error because you've redeclared `foo` and are trying to call `operator()` on a `std::string`, which isn't defined.

Comment: VC++ will warn you as well, if you set the warning level high enough. It's a level 4 warning for historical reasons.