# g++ compiler giving << type errors for expressions, but works in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, operator-overloading, cout

Ok, I think this might just be a version issue but I'm new to this. I have a main file that uses my overridden `<<` operator for a `BigInt` class I've implemented:

```
BigInt a = 3;
cout << a << endl;
cout << (a+a) << endl;
```

In Visual Studio, the compiler understands everything just fine and it runs great. But moving over to Ubuntu 14.04, `make`ing with my Makefile (which uses plain `g++` commands) gives me a bazillion type errors that are caused by the **third line** (and any other line that uses cout with an expression). If I remove the third line, it compiles great. The first error is:

```
main.cpp:23:8: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'BigInt')
    cout << (a+a);
         ^
```

This is confusing because my `<<` operator function takes reference args:

```
// in BigInt.h, in class' public section:

BigInt operator+(BigInt const& other) const;
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, BigInt& num);


// in BigInt.cpp:

BigInt BigInt::operator+(BigInt const& other) const {
    // call appropriate helper based on signs
    if (this->neg == other.neg) {
        return sum(other);
    }
    else {
        return difference(other);
    }
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream& os, BigInt& num) {
    if (num.dataLength == -1) {
        os << "**UNDEFINED**";
    }
    else {
        if (num.neg) os << "-";
        if (num.dataLength == 0) {
            os << "INFINITY";
        }
        else {
            // print each digit
            for (int i = num.dataLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                os << (short)num.data[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return os;
}
```

**So why does the first cout work but not the second? Is there a way to run `g++` such that it can work?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream& os, BigInt& num)
```

should take a `BigInt const& num`. [MSVC is non-compliant with regards to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19697616/1171191). g++ does not have this extension.

Make sure you change both the declaration in the header and the definition in the `BigInt.c` file. (Also, it is normal to use `.c` for files containing `C` code, and `.cpp` for files containing `C++` code.)

The reason is that `(a+a)` creates a *temporary* `BigInt`, which can't be bound to a non-`const` reference. The first `cout` works because `a` is a local variable, not a temporary, so can be passed as a normal (non-`const`) reference.

Aside from the issue with temporaries, it is good practice to apply [`const`-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness): make things `const` unless you actually need to change them. This can help prevent mistakes. Note that `std::ostream& os` cannot be `const`, you really do change it by writing to it.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is with

```
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, BigInt& num);
```

Since you take a `BigInt& num` this will not work with `(a+a)` as that crates a temporary and you cannot take a reference to a temporary.  It works in [MSVS as they have an extension to allow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug) but g++ does not.  Change it to

```
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BigInt& num);
```

Answer (score 6):

> So why does the first cout work but not the second?

Your `operator <<` takes its second argument by non-const reference. Temporaries like `(a+a)` cannot bind to that, so the second call is illegal. MSVC allows that as an extension, but it is not standard C++.

> Is there a way to run g++ such that it can work?

No. Fix your operator to use a const reference instead.